# How to set text above background image

Tags: html, css

I have question about element background image.

I have the following:

```
<div class="element" style="background-image: url(http://1.png); border: thin solid rgb(31, 101, 155); background-size: 133px 106px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <table class="title_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Element Title</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The structure can't be changed and I wish to have '`Element Title`' to show above the background image `(1.png)`. Currently, the background image cover the '`Element Title`'.

Are there anyways to do that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you can't change the HTML markup you will need to add script to make this happen.

Comment: `http://1.png` lovely URL ;)

Comment: Can you provide an example that shows this issue?  Because I can't reproduce the problem in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BhGbW/

Comment: @Steve sorry I can't, it's more complicated than my codes above.

Comment: Can you share the solution... just in case somebody comes here in the future and wonders.

Comment: It was my css codes. The texts actually shows. I only need to change the font color.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="title_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-image: url(http://1.png);">
```

and use `1.png`'s `width` & `height` for `table`.

Answer (score 0):

You can reposition the background.

Add this to your style:

```
background-position: 0px 1.1em;
```

It pushes the background down the size of a line height and a little more so the title won't be touching the background's top.

Answer (score 0):

I reuse your code with a different url:

```
<div class="element" style="background-image: url(http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/273203_100004092323558_2118346675_n.jpg); border: thin solid rgb(31, 101, 155); background-size: 133px 106px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
<table class="title_table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Element Title</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It still works fine, check your url.